# how to prevent data from being lost while pressing back button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-savedstate

The **MainActivity** code is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var number=0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
     number=savedInstanceState.getInt("Number",number)
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener{
        number +=5
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text="$number"

    }





}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt("Number",number)
    Log.i("MainActivity","Saved Instance Called")
}
```

}

See When I run the app and press back button data of number is not restored however when I press the home button data is restored.

Comment: You write to Logcat in `onSaveInstanceState()` Do you see the line with "Saved Instance Called" if you press the BACK button?

Comment: Yes  if I press home button but not when back button

Answer (score 2):

If you press the home button your app is put in the background and `Activity` is kept alive (but paused). At any point in time system can destroy it to free up memory and only keep save state bundle created by `onSaveInstanceState`. This bundle is then passed to `onCreate` as `savedInstanceState` when you come back to your app.

However when you press back button your activity is finished and app is closed. There will be no save state generated in this case, so if you want to keep your `number` value you have to store it in persistent storage like preferences, database, file etc. (depending on use case).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override onSaveInstanceState () method. For more details follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-activity-state-using-save-instance-state) link. Or else you can override onBackPressed method, store Number's value and then retrieve it again in onResume

Comment: This is incorrect.  The back button finishes the Activity, so the instance state won't be preserved.  Pawei's (correct) answer expands on this.